# Why does 01001000 equal H in Binary

Tags: math, binary

128 + 16 = 144 which isn't on the ASCII chart yet it equals H (decimal).

Can somebody help me with the conversion process because I'm quite new to binary so don't understand it that well but ASCII chart only goes up to 128 and H equals 72.

Summary: Why does 01001000 equal H in decimal.

Comment: No, 01001000 = 64 + 8 = 72 = `H` [in ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: I'm really new but the form of conversion I refer to is for example: 64 + 16 + 4 = 84 = T and T equals to 01010100, I believe I am talking about Hexidecimal yes.

Comment: No worries - everyone started somewhere,  So which are you confused on - the conversion from binary to decimal or the translation to ASCII characters?

Comment: That is not hexadecimal.  Hexadecimal is the conversion to "digits" from 0 to F (not ASCII characters), so 0100 1000 = 4 8 in hex, and 0101 0100 = 5 8 (not the decimal number "58", but the hex digits 5 and 8) note that 4 binary digits (0 or 1) equals 1 hex digit (0 to F).

Comment: Your mistake is assigning of values to the binary digits. You need to start with 1, not with 2.  The furthest digit to the right is the 1 digit, then the 2, the 4, etc.

Comment: The way I calculate binary to ASCII letters is through listing (from right to left) 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 etc. depending on the length of the binary e.g. if the binary is 1011 then I would list 1, 2, 4 and 8. So for example in 8 I would list 1, in 4 I would list 1, in 2 I would list 0 and in 1 I would list 1 and then I add them all together and that equals 11. Are you only supposed to go up to 64 in Hexidecimal?

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit character set, so the highest bit is 2^6 (64). This has nothing to do whatsoever with hexadecimal, I think you're quite confused about the whole thing. "01001000" doesn't "equal" to H in decimal, it's equal to 72, which corresponds to `H` on the ASCII table, or 48 in hexadecimal. Binary numbers are written with least significant digit right (just like decimals), so you always know "where to start" - from one (2^0). Your explanation of the conversion is weird, since you explain it entirely wrong (there's no 8 + 4 + 1, it's 1 + 2 + 8), and yet your result is correct (11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value `01001000` is translated to decimal like this

```
  0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
128s 64s 32s 16s  8s  4s  2s  1s
  0  64   0   0   8   0   0   0 = 72
```

Answer (score 2):

Your binary to decimal conversion is incorrect:

```
01001000 = 1 * 2^6 + 1 * 2^3 = 72
```

Recall that [the right-most binary digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit) corresponds to 2^0, not 2^1.

Comment: No MathJax support on SO?  Wasn't rendering for me.

Comment: No, but you can use html markup and unicode. 1 ⋅ 2<sup>6</sup>.